# Can a global variable set during a request leak across different requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, global-variables, server-side-rendering

If I set a global variable during processing of a request, can I leak that information into subsequent requests?

That is, the global variable is set on **every** request, and because nodejs is single-threaded I **think** I'm safe, but I'm asking here to increase confidence.

Here's my context:
I'm building a front-end service (Typescript + React) which does server side rendering, and I want to configure the application per-request.

To that end I'm using this technique:

`conf.ts`:

```
let CONFIG: any
export function setGlobal (state: any): void {
  CONFIG = state
}

export function getGlobal(): any {
  return CONFIG
}
```

`server.tsx` - where the Express app is configured:

```
const app = express()

app.get("/*", htmlEndpoint)

function htmlEndpoint (req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void {
  const foo = req.headers["x-foo"] as string || ""

  setGlobal({ foo })
  const context = {}
  const markup = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>,
  )

  <... respond with HTML, just boring boilerplate code ...>
}
```

And now somewhere deep in the React render-tree, a component can do this:

```
export function MyComponent() {
  console.log(getGlobal().foo)
}
```

Technically my question is very narrow in scope: By calling `setGlobal` on every request, am I running a real risk of leaking the contents of that global into other requests?

But more broadly I also welcome **any** kind of feedback and thoughts on the design. I dislike globals but haven't found another solution, but I also recognize I'm not an expert in any of my chosen technologies so it may be you can help open my eyes to alternatives. Very happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: It's a generally bad practice to use globals when there are alternative implementations that keep the variables in a local scope and pass them as arguments.  It may not cause you a specific problem here because of the single threaded nature of the main thread in node.js and the fact that you have no asynchronous operations between the settings of the global and the use of it.  But, why use a global at all?  Don't get in that habit.  Just keep the variable local and/or pass it as an argument to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - since Node is single threaded only one request is processed at a time, meaning that it would most certainly not be possible for the value to leak over into another request.

I think your approach is fine, although the code might not be as readable as it could be. Would it not be simpler to pass the value as a prop instead?

To do that you could do like this:

```
const global = { value: null }

// To set:
global.value = 'foo'

// To read:
console.log(global.value)
```

To pass it as a prop, you would declare your App component like:

```
function App(props) {
    // To access
    console.log(props.global.value)
}
```

And in your request:

```
<App global={global} />
```

You would then need to pass the value down the react tree to whichever component needs it.

Comment: How would I pass it as a prop? I first wanted to put it in a store but I can't use context outside the body of a React component, and I didn't want to drill-prop it all the to the specific components that uses it. I feel your reply indicates I might be missing something very simple, I'm ready to have my eyes opened :)

Comment: I edited my answer. In general, I try to avoid storing any values outside my React components (as globals). I instead create values in the parent and pass them down to my children. This makes the code more readable as you can see which components are using which variables simply by looking at the props.